# multiple spacing in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

Thesis office at my university has this rule regarding TOC -

- Chapter headings should have double space above and below them
- Subheadings should be single spaced.

To accomplish this, I have this in my latex source file

```
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{12pt} % space between whole chapter blocks`
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\vskip 16pt}
% single spaced section and subsection
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\vskip 6pt}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\vskip 6pt}
```

The problem I have is - because of the first two commands, I have unequal space distribution - something like

```
ABSTRACT
<28pt> 
DEDICATION
<28pt>
.
.
.
.
CHAPTER 1 TITLE
<28pt>
CHAPTER 2
<16pt>
...SUBHEADING 1
...SUBHEADTING 2
<16pt>
CHAPTER 3
<16pt>
.
.
.
```

I have used `\cftbeforesubsecskip` and `\cftbeforesecskip` also. These introduce spaces everywhere.

What I want is -

```
ABSTRACT
<16pt>
DEDICATION
<16pt>
.
.
.
<16pt>
CHAPTER 1 TITLE
<16pt>
CHAPTER 2
<16pt>
...SUBHEADING 1
...SUBHEADTING 2
<16pt>
CHAPTER 3
<16pt>
.
.
.
```

Could someone please tell me how I can get uniform spacing? Thanks a lot. I am clueless about this ... :(

This is what I get -

[image: TOC PAGE]

Answer (score 1):

REVISED SOLUTION to automate the process and also allow full use of optional argument in `\section`.  This solution modifies the `\section` definition.  If this is the first section of a chapter, a blank line is stacked above the section name in the toc (using the optional argument of the original `\section` definition).  You may have to tweak the actual stack gap (currently set as 18pt).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\let\svsection\section
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section[2][]{%
  \if0\@arabic\c@section%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax\firstsection{#2}\else\firstsection[#1]{#2}\fi%
  \else
    \ifx\relax#1\relax\svsection{#2}\else\svsection[#1]{#2}\fi%
  \fi}
\makeatother
\newcommand\firstsection[2][]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\svsection[\Longstack{\\#2}]{#2}\else
  \svsection[\Longstack{\\#1}]{#2}\fi
}
\setstackgap{L}{18pt}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}
\section[TOC Section Name]{A Section}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section[TOC Section Name]{A Section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

ORIGINAL SOLUTION:

You may have to tweak the actual stack gap (currently set as 18pt), but using the optional argument for the first section of every chapter will allow you to stack a blank line above that section heading in the toc.

Here, I codify that as `\firstsection{}`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newcommand\firstsection[1]{\section[\Longstack{\\#1}]{#1}}
\setstackgap{L}{18pt}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A Chapter}
\firstsection{A Section}
\section{A Section}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\firstsection{A Section}
\end{document}
```

[image]